# How to mount a disk image on a USB

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

I rescued data (Films) from an external hard drive with `ddrescue`
with this command,
`ddrescue -f -n /media/my_username/cff201e8-c3bc-.../rescue.img /media/my_username/cff201e8-c3bc-.../rescue.log`

The filename is `rescue.img` and it is stored on an external HDD.

Now I want to mount `rescue.img` as said [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316407/374478), so I do :

```
losetup -f 
losetup /dev/loop0 /path/rescue.img 
mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/dir
```

My `rescue.img` has 2 TB and my external hard drive where it is stored, only 3 TB. 
Therefore I think to need other external HDD. This my First Time that does it..

My question: Can I mount on this external HDD  or need other external HDD for doing it?

Can please someone to explain answer me it, Thanks!

Comment: Hello, could you provide the output of your commands by editing your question? I am not sure I understand what you are trying to say about disk capacity: mounting a disk is just creating a link to a specific directory on your computer, it does not mean copying files to you computer.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @Marc Vanhoomissen the disk capacity from external HDD where rescue.img is 3 TB and the  rescue.img 2TB .

Comment: @Marc Vanhoomissen as yet, I don't anything, first, I will information to come...

Comment: Is `rescue.img` an image of a whole drive or an image of a single partition?

Comment: I think a whole drive, I user this command, `ddrescue -f -n /media/my_username/cff201e8-c3bc-.../rescue.img  /media/my_username/cff201e8-c3bc-.../rescue.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit 1:

> My question: how to mount my rescue.img to the other external HDD?
>
> Can please someone to explain to me, how to does it with easy words,
>   Thanks!

Now I think I understand. There is a confusion about the words; I think you want to **clone** the image to another USB drive. But we need a bit more details before knowing exactly how to do it: If it is an image of a whole drive `/dev/sdx` or an image of a partition `/dev/sdxn`, where x is the device letter and n is the partition number.

### Edit 2:

If it is an image of the whole drive, you should have used something like

```
sudo ddrescue <some options> /dev/sdx /path/rescue.img /path/rescue.log
```

when you created the image file. If this is the case you can

- *either* use `ddrescue` in the reversed way to read from the image file and write to the **new** USB drive seen as a device `/dev/sdy`,
- *or* you can also do it with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) which is safer. You point to the image file as source and mkusb will help you select the **new** USB drive as target. Furthermore, if there is a GUID partition table, mkusb will fix the backup table at the tail end of the drive.

### Original answer:

- If `rescue.img` is an image of the whole drive with one or more partitions,

  - the easiest way is to **clone** it to another [new] drive of at least the same size as the original drive. You can do that with `ddrescue`, it is safer with [`mkusb`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). But it costs money to get a new drive.
  - You can try to mount the image with **`kpartx`**, which is easier than to identify manually where partitions start.
- If `rescue.img` is an image of a single partition, things are more straight-forward. It should be possible to loop mount it and have read access to the content, if the file system is healthy.

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /mnt/lp1
  sudo mount -o loop rescue.img /mnt/lp1
  ```
- Otherwise it should also be possible to recover files with **PhotoRec** or maybe repair the partition table with **TestDisk** or repair the file system with a tool made for that particular file system. See [this link](https://cgsecurity.org).

Comment: Thanks for you struggle, I will asked only if possible mount on the current external HDD or I muss to mount to other external HDD (for the place I to need on the external HDD...)

Comment: It is easiest to clone from the `rescue.img` image file to a new external HDD, and then operate on that drive with the rescue or repair work. But it might also work with `kpartx` directly on the `rescue.img` image file, and with rescue operations directly on the image file. It is worth trying the different alternatives, but make sure that you will not destroy the image file.

Comment: Very thanks foe you help! , i will to do as here to say https://www.ullright.org/ullWiki/show/mount-disk-image-files-kpartx

Comment: Good luck with `kpartx`, @dsaj34v :-)

Comment: Thanks! I wish you a nice Day!

Answer (score 1):

I use udiskctl.

```
udisksctl loop-setup -f /full/path/to/your.img
```

The command shows where the image ist mapped.

with `fdisk -l` you can see the partitions the file contains.

I forgot. You can mount ist with

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/loop?
```

Example

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/loop0p1
```